# Homestead is not loading the page

Tags: laravel, xampp, homestead, fedora-25

I'm new to homestead and I have encountered problems while installing it 
I can't use

> vagrant up

An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.
so I tried to install cloud base as I'm using Fedora 25 64 bit
https://atlas.hashicorp.com/fedora/boxes/25-cloud-base
and now I'm able to up my vagrant but once I try to ping my homestead.app 
all packets are lost and also I can't access it

- I'm running xampp in case it makes any differences
- here is my /etc/hosts

> 127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
>
> 192.168.10.10  homestead.app
>
> ::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

- here is my homestead.yaml

> ip: "192.168.10.10" memory: 2048 cpus: 1 provider: virtualbox
>
> authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
>
> keys:
>       - ~/.ssh/id_rsa
>
> folders:
>       - map: ~/projects
>         to: /home/vagrant/projects
>
> sites:
>       - map: homestead.app
>         to: /home/vagrant/projects/demo/public
>
> databases:
>       - demo

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to not use xampp with Homestead. Homestead comes with a full development environment including nginx server.

Install Homestead following this guide [Laravel Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/homestead)

Once installed and properly configured, run vagrant up, then vagrant ssh. Do not miss to [configure your nginx server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-laravel-with-an-nginx-web-server-on-ubuntu-14-04) to serve your application.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have followed the instructions there at laravel homestead guide, so am I supposed to remove my xampp ? also take a look at my homestead.yaml and /etc/hosts am I missing anything ?

Comment: You do not need to remove it. You can keep working your projects in xampp.  Your homestead.yaml and /etc/hosts look good.  Homestead will use nginx server in it's virtual environment. Proceed to configure nginx as described in my previous comment. After doing this run service nginx restart. You should access to your application by ip 192.168.10.10 or by domain homestead.app

Comment: what about i can't ping my homestead ?

Comment: check your nginx server status with: service nginx status . If its stopped, started it with service nginx start. Try to ping your homestead IP address after check nginx server status.   After try all this, if does not work, you should exit ssh session and run vagrant provision reload so your environment variables can refresh and load with the latest changes to your config files.